# table of contents starts by an arbitrary number

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am using `Beamer Presentation` to teach a Probability course in a university. At the first class, I introduced my class chapter 1 which included its sections 1 to 4, so my table of contents in the presentation numbered from 1 to 4. At the second class, I continue to present sections 5 to 8 which are still of chapter 1. Now I want the table of contents will start by 5 and end by 8. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have two separate presentations and you want to change the numbering of sections in one of them? Which theme(s) are you using?

Comment: Dear  Gonzalo Medina, `Do you have two separate presentations and you want to change the numbering of sections in one of them?`. That's true. I am using `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}`. However, if any other themes are better, I will use it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the behavior that you currently have and highlighting how it is different from the behavior that you would like to have will make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you could also keep the code for your lectures in a single file and use `beamer`'s `\includeonlylecture` to include lectures selectively. This automatically keeps the section numbers correct:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\includeonlylecture{lecturetwo}
\begin{document}

\part{Chapter First}
\lecture{Lecture One}{lectureone}
\section{Section First}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section First}
    In the first section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Second}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Second}
    In the second section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Third}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Third}
    In the third section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Fourth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Fourth}
    In the fourth section\dots
\end{frame}
\lecture{Lecture Two}{lecturetwo}
\section{Section Fifth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Fifth}
    In the fifth section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Sixth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Sixth}
    In the sixth section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Seventh}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Seventh}
    In the seventh section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Eighth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Eighth}
    In the eighth section\dots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: Second lecture only]

Commenting out the `\includeonlylecture` line:

[image: Both lectures]

EDIT: Forgot table of contents:

[image: ToC]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\includeonlylecture{lecturetwo}
\begin{document}

\part{Chapter First}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\lecture{Lecture One}{lectureone}
\section{Section First}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section First}
    In the first section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Second}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Second}
    In the second section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Third}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Third}
    In the third section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Fourth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Fourth}
    In the fourth section\dots
\end{frame}
\lecture{Lecture Two}{lecturetwo}
\section{Section Fifth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Fifth}
    In the fifth section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Sixth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Sixth}
    In the sixth section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Seventh}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Seventh}
    In the seventh section\dots
\end{frame}
\section{Section Eighth}
\begin{frame}{Chapter First}{Section Eighth}
    In the eighth section\dots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This does not, however, adjust the numbering. I guess it depends if you want to number according to the order of business for the day or the order of business for the chapter/course...

Answer (score 4):

It's enough to set the proper value for `\beamer@tocsectionnumber` in the second presentation, using, for example,

```
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=4
```

so the first section will be numbered 5, and setting the section number to the same value. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\makeatletter
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=4
\setcounter{section}{4}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section five}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\section{Test section five}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\section{Test section five}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\section{Test section five}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user46160 You're welcome! Glad I could help!

Comment: @user46160 I made a little addition to my answer that might be of interest.